# php-debug console not showing in atom

Tags: php, xdebug, atom-editor

I am using php-debug in atom with xdebug. Usually there would be two parts php-debug and php-console that are visible. In php-debug part, I could see the watchpoints, variables etc and also I could step in, step over, continue and stop the debugger. All of a sudden the php-debug part of the console has disappeared and I am not able to get it back. Has anyone faced and solved this issue?

Comment: https://discuss.atom.io/t/dont-work-xdebug-php-debug/32944

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you go to php-debug settings you can make sure the Current Panel Height is set to more than 0. Preferably at least 100px.

Then just restart Atom and you should see the panel appear.

Answer (score 0):

This solution worked for me. Just removed atom and made a clean install. Deleted the .atom folder and installed all the packages again. Now the php-debug is working correctly. By the way I had set the config.cson and xdebug configuration correctly including the remote and local path mappings. Glad I can see the variable explorer again!